# Project cannot depend on workspace Package - Bolt

Tags: project, project-management, lerna, monorepo, bolt

While using the Bolt Project Management tool (Like Lerna) I'm running into the following issues

```
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "awesome-typescript-loader"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "bestzip"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "webpack"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "webpack-cli"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "awesome-typescript-loader"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "bestzip"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "webpack"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "webpack-cli"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "@types/uuid"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "awesome-typescript-loader"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "bestzip"
error Project cannot depend on workspace Package "webpack"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Bolt is a relatively new kid in the block (Came out in 2017).

Verify if:

1. You have added the bolt entry inside package.json at the top level.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "myDepdencies": "^0.95.0"
},
"bolt": {
  "workspaces": [
    "my_mono_repo_source/*"
 ]
}
```

2. Verify that bolt workspaces entry is not using the multiglob:

```
// WRONG (Note the double asterisk **):
"bolt": {
  "workspaces": [
    "my_mono_repo_source/**"
 ]
```

```
// CORRECT (Note the single asterisk * ):
"bolt": {
  "workspaces": [
    "my_mono_repo_source/*",
    "my_mono_repo_source/deeply/nested/project_list/*",
 ]
```

3. Verify that all the sub-project.json are using the same semver of the packages.

Then run in your directory `bolt` and this will call `bolt install` in your behalf.